# Docker swarm execute command in a container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, pg-restore

So I'm setting up with Docker swarm.

I am now cool with the `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml myapp` command which replaces my former `docker-compose up`.

But one of my service is my DB and I need to `pgrestore` inside it.

Previously with compose, I would run:

`docker-compose run --rm postgres pg_restore --rest-of-command`

How can I do the same with `stack deploy`?

Unfortunately, the container created with compose is not the same as the one from `stack deploy`: the first one is called `myapp_postgres` while the second `myapp_postgres.1.zamd6kb6cy4p8mtfha0gn50vh`.

I guess I could write something like `docker exec 035803286af0` but then I loose all the benefits of the config from `docker-compose.yml`, which in this case is:

```
  postgres:
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    image: postgres:11.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - "..:/app" # toe make the dump accessible to the container
      - "/var/run/postgresql:/var/run/postgresql"
```

So this solution is not very [IaC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_code).

So ain't there a `docker service run` or something?

Thanks

Comment: do you want to run `pgrestore` upon running the container, or manually afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow docker image [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) (**Initialization scripts** section):

and create `*.sh` script under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` which will run `pg_restore ...` when Postgres container will run as part of the Docker service.

It doesn't seem to be a direct answer to your question, however it may achieve your goal of restoring the dump during Postgres initialization.

Comment: It seems like I can't run `pg_restore` at this step... :( https://stackoverflow.com/a/39275203/1620081

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. If some are curious, I could share my script.